# Significance of --indexed-ram-bundle for React Native bundling

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

Recently I've started using RAM bundles with inline requires to achieve better performance for React Native startup. To do so I've pretty much just [followed an official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#ram-bundles--inline-requires). It works fine, but in the Android part of the guide they say:

> Use the following lines on Android if you want to use a single indexed file:
>
> ```
> project.ext.react = [
>   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
>   extraPackagerArgs: ["--indexed-ram-bundle"]
> ]
> ```

What is the significance of `--indexed-ram-bundle`? Why would I want to, or not want to have a single indexed file?

I see that by default iOS appears to use a single indexed file, while Android will create a set of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While unable to determine with great detail why one would like to do `--indexed-ram-bundle` for Android [the Metro documentation](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/bundling/) does provide some information:

> **Indexed RAM bundle**
>
> This format composes the bundle as a binary file
> ...
> This structure is optimal for an environment that is able to load all code in memory at once
> ...
> This bundling is usually used by iOS.
>
> **File RAM bundle**
>
> Each module is stored as a file, with the name `js-modules/${id}.js`
> ...
> This bundling is usually used by Android, since package contents are zipped, and access to a zipped file is much faster. If the indexed format was used instead, all the bundled should be unzipped at once to get the code for the corresponding module.